# What are 'Armor Ruin' and 'Spell Ruin'?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

I've found a bunch of gear with bonuses to something called *Armor Ruin* and/or *Spell Ruin*.  It doesn't actually *say* what that means, though.

What are these two things?

[image: Armor Ruin]

[image: Spell Ruin]

Comment: My guess is the Armor Ruin decreases enemy defense on attack, and the Spell Ruin lowers their magic. Just a guess though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the cursor to the A. Ruin and S. Ruin boxes on the status menu screen, they'll be defined at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Armor Ruin: Determines how much armor your physical attacks will ignore.]
[image: Spell Ruin: Determines how much resist your magical attacks will ignore.]

> Armor Ruin: Determines how much armor your physical attacks will ignore.
>
> Spell Ruin: Determines how much resist your magical attacks will ignore.

All the stats have similar descriptions.  This information is also available in the game's manual, though if you're like me you probably didn't know the game has one.

Comment: Huh, I wonder if there's a way to see these when using a gamepad.  Thanks!